# Why can I read ksqldb streams but not topics within ksql client?

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, ksqldb, sasl

I am testing ksqldb on AWS EC2 instances in the latest release (confluent 5.5.1) and have an access problem that I can't solve.

I have a secured Kafka sever (SASL_SSSL, SASL mode PLAIN), an unsecured Schema Registry (another issue with Avro Serializers, but ok for the moment), and a secured KSQL Server and Client.

- Topics are filled properly with AVRO data (value only, no key) from a JDBC source connector.
- I can access the KSQL Server with ksql without issues
- I can access KSQL REST API without issues
- When I list topics within ksql, I get the correct list.
- When I select a push stream, I get messages when I push something into the topic (with Kafka Connect, in my case).
- BUT: When I call "print topic" I get a ~60 sec block in the client, followed by a 'Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata'.

The ksql-kafka.log goes wild with repeated entries like

```
[2020-09-02 18:52:46,246] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=null] Bootstrap broker ip-10-1-2-10.eu-central-1.compute.internal:9093 (id: -3 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1037)
```

The corresponding broker log shows

```
Sep  2 18:52:44 ip-10-1-6-11 kafka-server-start: [2020-09-02 18:52:44,704] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1002] Failed authentication with ip-10-1-2-231.eu-central-1.compute.internal/10.1.2.231 (Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake.) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

This is my ksql-server.properties file:

```
ksql.service.id= hf_kafka_ksql_001
bootstrap.servers=ip-10-1-11-229.eu-central-1.compute.internal:9093,ip-10-1-6-11.eu-central-1.compute.internal:9093,ip-10-1-2-10.eu-central-1.compute.internal:9093
ksql.streams.state.dir=/var/data/ksqldb
ksql.schema.registry.url=http://ip-10-1-1-22.eu-central-1.compute.internal:8081
ksql.output.topic.name.prefix=ksql-interactive-
ksql.internal.topic.replicas=3
confluent.support.metrics.enable=false

# currently the keystore contains only the ksql server and the certificate chain to the CA
ssl.keystore.location=/var/kafka-ssl/ksql.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=kspassword
ssl.key.password=kspassword
ssl.client.auth=true
# Need to set this to empty, otherwise the REST API is not accessible with the client key.
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=

# currently the truststore contains only the CA certificate
ssl.truststore.location=/var/kafka-ssl/client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=ctpassword

security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
    username="ksql" \
    password="ksqlsecret";
listeners=https://0.0.0.0:8088
advertised.listener=https://ip-10-1-2-231.eu-central-1.compute.internal:8088

authentication.method=BASIC
authentication.roles=admin,ksql,cli
authentication.realm=KsqlServerProps

# authentication for producers, needed for ksql commands like "Create Stream"
producer.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=HTTPS
producer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
producer.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
producer.ssl.truststore.location=/var/kafka-ssl/client.truststore.jks
producer.ssl.truststore.password=ctpassword
producer.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
producer.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
    username="ksql" \
    password="ksqlsecret";

# authentication for consumers, needed for ksql commands like "Create Stream"
consumer.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=HTTPS
consumer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
consumer.ssl.truststore.location=/var/kafka-ssl/client.truststore.jks
consumer.ssl.truststore.password=ctpassword
consumer.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
consumer.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
    username="ksql" \
    password="ksqlsecret";
```

I call ksql with

```
ksql --user cli --password test --config-file /var/kafka-ssl/ksql_cli.properties https://ip-10-1-2-231.eu-central-1.compute.internal:8088'
```

This is my ksql client configuration ksql_cli.properties:

```
security.protocol=SSL
#ssl.client.auth=true
ssl.truststore.location=/var/kafka-ssl/client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=ctpassword
ssl.keystore.location=/var/kafka-ssl/ksql.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=kspassword
ssl.key.password=kspassword
```

JAAS config, included as Parameter on service start

```
KsqlServerProps {
  org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.spi.PropertyFileLoginModule required
  file="/var/kafka-ssl/cli.password"
  debug="false";
};
```

with cli.password containing the authentication users and passwords for the ksql client.

I call ksql with

```
ksql --user cli --password test --config-file /var/kafka-ssl/ksql_cli.properties https://ip-10-1-2-231.eu-central-1.compute.internal:8088'
```

I possibly have tried any permutation of keys, settings etc but to no avail. Obviously there is something wroing in key management. For me, it is surprising that usings streams is ok but the low-level topics is not.

Has someone found a solution for that issue? I am really running ou of ideas here. Thanks.

Comment: oh, and all the ACLs are set, of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! It was easy to overlook - the client's configuration needs of course. a SASL setting...

```
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
```